# Android - Binding in XML with Companion Object?

Tags: xml, android-studio, kotlin

I'm trying to bind some colors in my widget xml layout to a function that returns a boolean.

The function looks like this

```
fun getIsWidgetDarkModeEnabled(): Boolean {
        val isWidgetDarkModeEnabled = 
 preferences?.getBoolean("isWidgetDarkModeEnabled", true)
    return isWidgetDarkModeEnabled ?: true
    }
```

I'm not quite sure how I could bind this value to my XML.

I have tried something like this but it just gives me errors

```
<data>
    <variable name="values" type="com.team.project.ui.main.GlobalFunctions"/>
</data>
```

I get the error on data saying: Cannot resolve class data
And on value: Cannot resolve class variable

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?